# Using first-child tag on several p tags?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

i recently got into html & css and i don't know much . I got stuck while trying to use first-child selector on several paragraphed link tags . It is something like this :
`<p><a href="link">text</a></p>
 <p><a href="link">text</a><p>
 <p><a href="link">text</a><p>`

So is it possible to use the first-child in this situation to make it affect only first paragraph ? If not what would be the best way to do it ?

(Sorry for my english..)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: It would help if you'd (a) show the CSS you've tried and (b) explain what it is you're trying to *do*.

Comment: This would also require information about the HTML page as a whole, since it depends on context whether the first of the `p` elements in the question matches the `:first-child` selector.

Comment: `:first-child` pseudo-class represents the first child element of its parent. In this case `a:first-child` selects all the `<a>` elements as they're the first child of their parent `<p>`. You may need something like [`p:first-of-type a`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type) selector to target the links which are descendant of the first paragraph. (Considering the paragraphs are siblings)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use CSS3 to do this such as code below to do what you are wanting to do.

```
p a {
  color: red;
}
p:first-child a{
  color: blue;
}
```

This will however, mean that it will only work in modern browsers that support CSS3 such as IE9+, Chrome, Safari and Firefox

Example of this working : http://embed.plnkr.co/67O3p6EBS1xmJ8w8m1e1/preview

Comment: The rules do not apply to `p` elements at all. Whether they apply to some `a` elements inside some `p` elements depends on markup context that was not disclosed. The `:first-child` pseudo-element is in CSS 2.1 and well supported.

Comment: The point of the question is to look at p tags and set styling on the a tag within the first p tag. I fail to see the problem with the answer?

Comment: The question as asked is about styling `p` elements (called “tags” in the question). You might be right in guessing what the purpose really is, especially judging from the acceptance of the answer, but the answer still does not answer the question *actually asked*. It also contains wrong information, and it fails to work whenever the `p` elements have any sibling (say, `h1`) before them.